# c2dm device unregistered automatically

Tags: android, push-notification, android-c2dm

I have written an application that uses C2DM.  I can register devices and send messages fine, however I get devices that are suddenly unregistered, and therefore stop receiving messages.  I thought I could handle this with the code below, but it appears the "unregister" intent is not received(this is not confirmed, but the device is not re-registered).

My questions are is this normal for devices to be unregistered out of the blue? If so is the "unregister" message sent to the device? How can you handle this without having an interruption of service?  Are others experiencing this also?  I could handle this with having the user push a button in the app to re-register, but I do not want to do this unless I have to.  Also have considered keeping the status of devices(registered, not registered) on the server and then have the app periodically check to see if the device is still registered.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
public class MyC2dmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private static String KEY = "c2dmPref";
private static String REGISTRATION_KEY = "registrationKey";
SharedPreferences prefs;

private Context context;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    this.context = context;
    if (intent.getAction().equals(
            "com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION")) {
        handleRegistration(context, intent);
    } else if (intent.getAction().equals(
            "com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE")) {
        handleMessage(context, intent);
    }
}

private void handleRegistration(Context context, Intent intent) {
    final SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = Util.getSharedPreferences(this.context);
    String email = sharedPrefs.getString(Util.ACCOUNT_NAME, "");//

    prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    //String email = prefs.getString("email_for_c2dm", "");//
    String registration = intent.getStringExtra("registration_id");
    if (intent.getStringExtra("error") != null) {
        // Registration failed, should try again later.
        Log.d("c2dm", "registration failed");
        String error = intent.getStringExtra("error");
        if (error == "SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE") {
            Log.d("c2dm", "SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE");
        } else if (error == "ACCOUNT_MISSING") {
            Log.d("c2dm", "ACCOUNT_MISSING");
        } else if (error == "AUTHENTICATION_FAILED") {
            Log.d("c2dm", "AUTHENTICATION_FAILED");
        } else if (error == "TOO_MANY_REGISTRATIONS") {
            Log.d("c2dm", "TOO_MANY_REGISTRATIONS");
        } else if (error == "INVALID_SENDER") {
            Log.d("c2dm", "INVALID_SENDER");
        } else if (error == "PHONE_REGISTRATION_ERROR") {
            Log.d("c2dm", "PHONE_REGISTRATION_ERROR");
        }
} else if (intent.getStringExtra("unregistered") != null) {
        // unregistration done, new messages from the authorized sender will
        // be rejected
        Log.d("c2dm", "unregistered");
        SharedPreferences c2dmPrefs=context.getSharedPreferences(KEY,     Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        c2dmPrefs.edit().putString("registrationKey", "");
        c2dmPrefs.edit().commit();
                    //RegisterDevice launches the registration intent to get a new regKey
        RegisterDevice register=new      RegisterDevice(FirefighterLog.getInstance());
} else if (registration != null) {
        Log.d("c2dm", registration);
        updateServerRegId(registration))  //sends regID to server and stores
            Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences(KEY,
                    Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putString(REGISTRATION_KEY, registration);
            editor.commit();
            Toast.makeText(context, "Device registered successfully",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
```

NOTE:  The updateServerRegId() sends the new regID to the server and overwrites if it already exists.  I am using RequestFactory and sending it as an entity to appengine.

android Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.xxx.someapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <permission android:name="com.xxx.someapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
              android:protectionLevel="signature" />

  <receiver android:name=".C2DM.MyC2dmReceiver"     android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
      <!-- Receive the actual message -->
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
          <category android:name="com.xxx.someapp" />
      </intent-filter>
      <!-- Receive the registration id -->
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
          <category android:name="com.xxx.someapp" />
      </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
```

Comment: How soon after an initial registration do these "un-registrations" occur? Hours, days, weeks?

Comment: Can you post your Android Manifest where the C2DM Receiver is defined?

Comment: @MisterSquonk Time seems to vary, but usually weeks.  I haven't had enough testing to know exactly.

Comment: @Kevin android manifest added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could this just be a case of Google refreshing the registration ID? From the C2DM docs for [Lifecycle Flow](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/index.html#lifecycle) in the *Enabling C2DM* section...

> ...
>
> 2.If the registration is successful, the C2DM server broadcasts a REGISTRATION Intent which gives the application a registration ID.
>
> The application should store this ID for later use. **Note that Google may periodically refresh the registration ID, so you should design your application with the understanding that the REGISTRATION Intent may be called multiple times.** Your application needs to be able to respond accordingly.
>
> ...
>
> The registration ID lasts until the application explicitly unregisters itself, **or until Google refreshes the registration ID for your application.**

There's nothing in the documentation that states that an Intent with the "unregister" extra will be sent as a result of re-registration. The only time that is mentioned is when the app explicitly un-registers itself.

Looking at your code, it seems incomplete - it's not clear how you handle registration or the possibility of a re-registration (when Google refresh the registration ID for example).

In your response to my comment on your question, you say it's "usually weeks". If you had said hours (or perhaps even days) I probably would have dismissed the idea that a re-registration is causing the problem. Weeks, however, seems a perfectly reasonable time period for Google to refresh the registration ID.

Just a thought.

**EDIT:** Well as long as you're happy that `updateServerRegId()` is working correctly and updating with the new `registration_id` (if necessary) then I can't see much else to point a finger at.

I still wonder if this is a case of maintaining an invalid (expired) registration ID however. Just looking at the docs further...

> The application receives a REGISTRATION Intent broadcast whenever the application server attempts to send a message to it. But registration IDs can be nonexistent or invalid for a variety of reasons:
>
> - If an application is running for the first time, it has no registration ID yet.
> - If the application unregistered, it has no registration ID.
> - The C2DM server periodically refreshes registration IDs.

Assuming the first two don't apply that only leaves the last.

You say in your original question that "I get devices that are suddenly unregistered, and therefore stop receiving messages". Have you looked at the possible error codes in the 200 response when sending messages to theses devices? Look at the response code section of [How the Application Server Sends Messages](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/index.html#push), it may give you a better indication of what's happening.

By the way, one possibly unrelated thing (but I thought I'd mention it)...

```
if (error == "SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE")
```

...don't compare `Strings` using `==`, always use `.equals(...)`. If you are getting errors along the way, comparing for error strings in that way isn't going to work and you might be missing something.

Comment: Ok, thanks for posting that text.  I had remembered reading along those lines.  This does sound like what is happening, however the way my app is written it should be registered again when it is refreshed.  I will post more code that shows how I handle the registration intent.

Comment: After looking at the ChromeToPhone source I am wondering if I may need a wakelock.  ChromeToPhone uses one on it's Receiver.  In my app the initial registration happens when the user is using the app. When the refresh happens, the phone will likely be asleep and perhaps the receiver is being killed before the registration ID is sent to my server...

Comment: Sorry, I don't know about the wakelock but I'd really hope that wasn't the case - I wouldn't want my app to keep a user's phone 'awake' in any way simply based on the vague possibility that Google may refresh the registration ID. Besides, `BroadcastReceivers` registered in the manifest don't need the phone to be awake to receive messages. Anyway, sorry I've run out of ideas although I edited the end of my post - not sure it will help although take notice of the bit about comparing strings with `==`. Good luck.

Comment: I have looked at the responses from the server when sending messages and I get a 200 repsonse "NotRegistered".  I did not plan to keep the device awake all the time with the wakelock, only when a c2dm intent was received.  It would be removed once all work was completed. It appears to be the practice used in the ChromeToPhone app.  Running out of options here...Thanks for input and pointing out the use of == with strings, not sure how that got in there.

Comment: I found this post and is tangential to my problem.  Seems a wakelock may be needed. http://groups.google.com/group/android-c2dm/browse_thread/thread/5a94ec435cc865b2/2dff6b98c258779c

Comment: My device regIDs were being refreshed and they were not being updated because I was attempting to get the new regid on the Broadcast receiver and the system was destroying the process before I complete the operation